# How to initiate String array in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I would like to know how to start an array similar to this `String [] errorSoon = {"Hello", "World"};` in `Kotlin`. How is done?

Comment: You can use this library function arrayOf("a","b").

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `arrayOf()` fuction as it described in Kotlin [Basic Type](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html) article.
Your code will be the next:

```
val errorSoon = arrayOf("Hello", "World")
```

Answer (score 4):

Declare array at global

```
names = arrayOf(String())
```

Now in onCreate method Initialize you array with value

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    //Init array here
    names = arrayOf("Friends List", "Notification")
}
```

Comment: Please add a short description of how your code answers the question. It would help others understand your answer better.

Answer (score 2):

```
val array= arrayOf("Hello", "World")
```

And there is one more way to create String Array.

```
// Creates an Array<String> with values ["0", "1", "4", "9", "16"]
val asc = Array(5, { i -> (i * i).toString() })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `arrayOf()` to create array in `Kotlin`

```
val errorSoon = arrayOf("a", "b", "c")
```

to get values from array use below code

```
for (i in errorSoon.indices) {
    print(errorSoon[i]+" ")
}
```

You can read more **[here about it](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html)**

Answer (score 1):

```
val errorSoon = arrayOf("Hello", "World")
```

Answer (score 1):

array of strings can be initialized with square brackets too.

```
values = [ "a", "b" ]
```

Comment: not supported in Android's Kotlin: "collection literals are outside of annotations"